# Is there a quicker/neater syntax for listing items in Xpath 1?

Tags: xpath-1.0

```
[not(@id ='10281147' or @id='3157344949' or @id='6099815862' or @id='6100309416' or @id='6104595405' or @id='6691194319')]
```

Using Xpath 1, is there a simpler (& hopefully speedier)  way to list items as above?

Comment: please show the example xml also

Comment: In XPath 2.0+ you can structure the same as `not(@id = ('10281147', '3157344949', '6099815862', '6100309416', '6104595405', '6691194319'))` where the = will return true if at least one item in the sequence is matched.  In XPath 1, doubtful you can do much more than normal De Morgans logical equivalents which are not necessarily simpler or speedier assuming there is no pattern in the id values you can take advantage of (to do a string contains() or something like that).